# How can I change the value in a nested array of objects, after a button click using JQuery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a voting app using Node.js, Javascript, JQuery, Jade and a json file for practice.

In short, I'm trying to count the votes for each option to eventually render it into a chart. Specifically I was trying to add + 1 to the object value `{"value": 0}` in the json each time someone chooses a radio button correlated to the option and hits submit. I can get to the e.g. `{"option": "Puppies","value": 0}` in my JQuery and I've been trying to find a way to change the object value within the `$("#btnVote").click(function(){})`.  I'm not sure if that would be possible or the best way.

Here is a sample of the JSON database.

```
  [{
"name": "Puppies or Kitties",
"id": "f2754172-1c58-41ed-ae84-74e046888adb",
"choices" : [{"option": "Puppies","value": 0}, {"option": "Kittens","value": 0}],
"admin": true}]
```

Here is the Jade I am using to dynamically render the poll options.

```
form(method="post")
    fieldset.form-group
        h1 #{poll.name}
    form
        table
            each choice in poll.choices
                tr
                    td=choice.option

                        input(type='radio',value=choice.value id=choice.option name="Answer" class="clsAnswer", style='margin:10px')

        br
        input(type="button", value="Submit Vote", id="btnVote")
```

[A visual if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP6Hf.png)
Here is the JQuery I've used so far;

```
//Radio button vote function
$("#btnVote").click(function () {
    var selected = $(".clsAnswer:checked");
    if (!selected.val()) {
        alert("No Choice Was Made!");
    }
    else {
        var optionName = $('input[type=radio][name=Answer]:checked').attr('id');
        var selectedValue = selected.val();
        selectedValue = parseInt(selectedValue);
        alert("Value: " + selectedValue + "  " +  optionName);
    };
});
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: easy, navigate to that specific property within your structure and change it, just like you would any other object property, array value, or variable.

Comment: Thank you for commenting Kevin B but could you be more specific? I'm relatively new to this so not sure what you mean by 'that specific property'  and within my 'structure'.  Could you show me some links or give a specific example? Regardless, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: `thearray[0].whatever.property.you.want = 5;`

Comment: Thank you again Kevin B.  I'll go work on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that you can change the object value in this case, either through your JSON being in a database such as mongodb or through cookies as a temporary change.

The current JQuery is set up to receive the static html and not from the JSON file.

Since the JSON file is used as practice in the folder hierarchy and static (as well as the html), this current setup will not render updating the object value in JSON or even as a temporary change as you would maybe see in cookies. 
One other alternative would be to use node.js and create a new JSON file but that is not what is being aimed at in this application.